# Distinguishing 3rd cousin from half sibling?

Tags: england, 2000s-decade

Two sisters married two men, one gave birth to my mother. The other gave birth to the mother of Miss X
We grew up believing we (miss x and I,) were distant cousins.
A statement in an argument by my mother was “he cannot marry her, she’s his sister.”

This has since been denied.

However, we both Miss X and I suffer the same illnesses and doctors have told us that it’s likley hereditary.

Miss X’s father is deceased. He is thought to have had a liaison with my mother. My mother and supposed father survive but refuse testing. How can we find out if we are siblings or cousins? Miss X and are desperate to know the truth but have discontinued our relationship because of this. It is causing great distress to us and to the whole families concerned.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Either way, you would either be first cousins or half-siblings. This is tough because the DNA matching range between half-siblings and cousins can overlap, making it hard to distinguish the type of relation without testing her father. Does her father have living siblings you could test?

Comment: None that are willing I’m afraid. Tbh the whole family have turned their back for even asking for dna. Even though it’s one of the principal players that first made the comments that set this ball in motion.

Answer (score 2):

If you both undertake an autosomal DNA test, like the one from AncestryDNA, then the amount of shared centimorgans fed into this [tool](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcm) from the DNA Painter project mentioned in [this blog post](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/2017/10/07/using-shared-matches-a-quick-example/) should make it simple to distinguish a 3rd cousin from a half sibling.